# Related products block to right sidebar in Product page In magento 1.9

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.9, rwd

I want to transfer the related products block from product detail page to right sidebar but when I try to rearrange it on the catalog.xml file, view all product catalog page is missing. is there a right way for me to do it?

I'm using RWD theme

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change product page layout 1coumn to  2column right Using

```
 <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

to

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

and add this

```
<reference name="right">
 <block type="catalog/product_list_related_right" name="catalog.product.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Comment: wow! this code helps me since I already have the block code for related products

I put it on the reference name "right"

<reference name="right">
<block type="catalog/product_list_related_right" name="catalog.product.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" />
</reference>